# Logtsash Plugin for CosmosDB to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, azure-cosmosdb

Can you please suggest which logstash plugin is used for pulling data from Cosmos DB to Elasticsearch using Logstash?

If no such plug-ins, is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Logstash plugins for Microsoft Azure Services](https://unofficialism.info/posts/logstash-plugins-for-azure-services/) and this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logtsash-plugin-for-cosmosdb-to-elasticsearch/168008),it seems that the cosmos db input plugin is not supported so far.

All i can find by now,you could use [ADF copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to transfer your cosmos db data into above supported input source data residences,then complete subsequent work.

For example,use ADF to transfer cosmos db into sql db and follow this [link](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-copy-sql-server-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash/) to integrate with your elasticsearch service.